# mysql give parameter to subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I got a nice complex mysql query here.

What I want, is for each week, to see the sum of a value for the users who were active in that week.
(active user is a user who joined <= $week and left > $week)

Now what I did was to have first make a list of all weeks.
Then provide subselects to get the value that is calculated for each week.

However, how do I give the value of the week to each subquery?
My example only gives the result for 1 hardcoded week (201444).
So instead of

```
WHERE yearweek(giveaway.closed) <= 201444
```

I would need something like

```
WHERE yearweek(giveaway.closed) <= $yearweek
```

How to fill each row?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e050/1)

```
SELECT 
    weeks.yearweek AS 'yearweek',
    COALESCE(valueGiven.valueGiven,0) AS 'valueGiven',
    COALESCE(valueWon.valueWon,0) AS 'valueWon',
    round(valueGiven / valueWon*100,2) AS 'ratio'
FROM 
    (
        select yearweek(selected_date,3) as yearweek
        from 
            (
                select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date 
                from
                (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union
                     select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
                (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union
                     select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
                (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union
                     select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
                (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union
                     select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
                (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union
                     select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4
            ) v
        where selected_date between '2014-08-01' and now()
            AND date_format(selected_date, '%w') = 6
        order by yearweek
    ) as weeks

LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            '201444' AS yearweekGA,
            sum(giveaway.valuegiven) AS valueGiven
        FROM giveaway

        LEFT JOIN user
            ON user.steamid = giveaway.creatorid

        WHERE yearweek(giveaway.closed) <= 201444
            AND giveaway.winnerid IS NOT NULL
            AND yearweek(user.joined) <= 201444
            AND (user.leftgroup is NULL  OR  yearweek(user.leftgroup) > 201444)
    ) AS valueGiven
    ON weeks.yearweek = valueGiven.yearweekGA

LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            '201444' AS yearweekGA,
            sum(giveaway.valuewon) AS valueWon
        FROM giveaway

        LEFT JOIN user
            ON user.steamid = giveaway.winnerid

        WHERE yearweek(giveaway.closed) <= 201444
            AND giveaway.winnerid IS NOT NULL
            AND yearweek(user.joined) <= 201444
            AND (user.leftgroup is NULL  OR  yearweek(user.leftgroup) > 201444)
    ) AS valueWon
    ON weeks.yearweek = valueWon.yearweekGA

ORDER BY weeks.yearweek
```

Expected results:

```
201443  2.00    2.00    100.00
201444  2.00    2.00    100.00
...
201515  2.00    3.00    66.67
201516  2.00    3.00    66.67
...
201622  3.00    3.00    100.00
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do the sqlfiddle. I am sure one of us can help with this. What are the expected results shown in some columnar for so we know we got it right?

Comment: @drew I've added the expected results.
It's too bad my data set is small, because the fiddle wouldn't allow me to upload more data rows.

Comment: maybe you could break it down into a smaller concept (or highlight the part you are referring to), to know what you are giving to what. What it is you want handed to a subquery and which subquery. You know it, but we don't just by a quick glance. And how the lack of data to proof it can be addressed.